# Обновить переменную во Vue.js не вызвав Watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Можно ли во Vue.js скрыто от watcher обновить переменную?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: подобная задача обсуждается здесь - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      variable: 1337,
      lock: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    change () {
      this.variable = Math.random() * 1000 | 0
    }
  },
  watch: {
    variable () {
      if (this.lock)
        return
      
      alert('Вы изменили!')
      this.lock = true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" style="height: 1000px; background: yellow;">
  Значение: {{ variable }}<br>
  Слежение: {{ !lock }}<br>
  <button @click="change">Изменить</button>
  <button @click="lock = false">Снова следить</button>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/LJVKGM?editors=1010)